Can I disable the alpha channel in the UV editor?
I have a material using an RGBA .tga image file as the texture, where the RGB values are used as both the Base Color and the Emission Color and the Alpha value is used as the Emission Strength. Large parts of the material aren't glowing, so those parts of the image have an Alpha value of zero. As a consequence, large parts of the image are invisible in the UV Editor, making it impossible to directly see where on the image I am placing the UVs. I've looked for a way to fix that, but all I can find is the option to invert the Alpha channel, which just swaps the areas I can and can't see.
Can I disable the Alpha channel in the UV editor pane so the entire image is visible at once?

Like every image window of Blender, you'll find these options here on the top right corner of the window :


Thank you for pointing it out! That menu was hidden from me because the pane was too narrow; I had to make it full-screen to see it. Perhaps Blender should wrap the menu bar or provide some clear indication that things are being cut off...

@Lawton You can move the top bar horizontally by pressing the middle mouse button and dragging.

@Lawton ...or you can move the top bar by rolling the mouse wheel.
